# HIVE: remove numbers from the end of the string

Tags: regex, apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to remove an integer from the end of the string/column so I can use it in a group by.
Here is an example

```
Apartment-12
House-3
Big-Apartment-6
Condo-11
```

needs to transform to

```
Apartment
House
Big-Apartment
Condo
```

I tried all the following, unsuccessfully:

```
select regexp_replace('Apartment-15', "-/\d+$/", "");
select regexp_replace('Apartment-15', "-\d+$", "");
select regexp_replace('Apartment-15', "-\d+$", "");
select regexp_replace('Apartment-15', "-\d*$", "");
```

Appreciate any help in explain how and *why* it isn't work.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply double the backslashes:

```
select regexp_replace('Apartment-15', "-\\d+$", "");
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems `select regexp_replace('Apartment-15', "-[0-9]+$", "");` worked but don't know why `\d` doesn't!

Comment: Thank you. [0-9] is safe in many regular expressions, too.